# How to use lambda for a scope syntax

Tags: activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm using the following scope in a Rails 3.2 application:

```
scope :consumable, lambda { where('expiration_date > ?', Date.today) }
```

What is the correct syntax to achieve the same in Rails 4 with Ruby 2.0?

Comment: This is actually not due to Rails 4, it is Ruby version dependent.

Answer (score 2):

```
scope :consumable, -> { where('expiration_date > ?', Date.today) }
```